# Flask dynamic checkboxes

Tags: python, flask

This is pretty straightforward: I have a list of ids and I want to display them to the user as a series of checkboxes. The user should select the ones he wants then check which ones are selected and execute a function. Here's my code:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, redirect
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField,widgets, SelectMultipleField
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
@app.route("/example", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def example():
      form = FlaskForm()
      ids= ['a','b','c']
      if request.method == 'POST':
          selected_ids = request.form.getlist("ids")
          if form.validate():
              flash('nice')
          else:
              flash('something went wrong')

      return render_template('example.html', form=form, ids= ids)
```

and my template.html:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">IDs to select</legend>
                {%for i in ids%}
                <li>
                        <input type = "checkbox" id = "id_{{i}}" name = "ids" value = "1">
                        <label for="id1">{{i}}</label>
                 </li>
                {% endfor %}

            </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">GO</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

However, this creates a 500 error when I submit. Where am I going wrong? ANy suggestions highly appreciated!

Comment: first things can you give some extra detail? I suppose you are calling the API with POST method seeing that your code doesn't have a condition for GET, isn't it?

Comment: well POST is only when I submit the form right? When I GET I just need to render the list.

Comment: mmmm is the example.html in the same path of your flask .py file?

Comment: No, as per convention it’s in the templates folder

Comment: so you need specify the path if you didn't somewhere else... otherwise your code is searching for example.html on the same path of your flask.py file

Comment: If there was a problem with the template path, the GET request would also error and the page wouldn't load at all